# Is there a way to disable the picture 'bloop' in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

In pokemon go it annoys me that even if you disable all sound, when you need to start the camera for a scan it will always do a loud bloop.

Is there a way to disable it? Kinda annoying when you are listening to music only to be blasted by it when you get a poffin scan quest.

Comment: I don't have this problem at all. It might be specific to your model of phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a Samsung device you may be able to run [Sound Assistant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.soundassistant), which is an official app that let's you control volume on a per-app basis.

Otherwise [App Volume Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spycorp.appvolumecontrol) or a similar app may work, as long as its Service works.

Comment: It is also an artifact of the laws of Japan and south Korea to try to stop people from snapping pictures of people without there knowledge.

Comment: @Styxsksu Excellent point. I don't think it's only those countries that have this law, but I'm not sure which others do.